# Heroku Review apps, set Meteor ROOT_URL correctly on deployment to review app

Tags: javascript, heroku, meteor, git-flow

Example app.json at the root of a directory. I'm trying to figure out how I could take the HEROKU_APP_NAME and set the ROOT_URL variable so I don't have to manually set it each pull request.

```
{
  "name":"Advanced App",
  "scripts":{
    "postdeploy":"rake db:setup && bin/bootstrap"
  },
  "env":{
    "HEROKU_APP_NAME": {
      "required": true
    },
    "HEROKU_PARENT_APP_NAME": {
      "required": true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Setting the IP address as 0.0.0.0 should work.